# PCB Edge to Edge Connectors

Tags: pcb, connector

I'm trying to find a way to connect PCB boards edge-to-edge so that I can make a "train" of PCB boards in a row.

It seems to me that this should be straight forward to do using a a female to female edge connector, but when I've looked for such a beast I've only found one solution that's both overly large and overly expensive (http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/EAC10FSLN/S9348-ND/2618449?cur=USD).

Any ideas how I can best accomplish this?

Comment: Molex have all sorts of this kind of thing in their catalogue, although that requires soldering the connectors on the edge of the PCB rather than literally edge connectors on both PCBs.

Comment: I would use the edge of one PCB as the male connector, and put the female connector on the other, much like PCI cards. There's plenty of connectors out there, from classic D-Subs to high density backplane connectors, that would work to join two adjacent PCB's.

Comment: I agree with Leon. Those connectors tend to be quite expensive, especially for higher current capabilities. Standard connectors may work for you and will definitively be cheaper. Look at the sites of Molex and Samtec. These guys have plenty of connectors and a lot of custom solutions.

Comment: You didn't mention what type of signals you will need to send through: are these high current, or high frequency? How many signals? There are many different options. Also what is the environment - does the solution need to accommodate flexing?

Comment: Perhaps AVX INTERCONNECT 00-9159
([picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qFLCw.jpg))

Comment: Sullins Corp have double female edge to edge connectors, you could try those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use suitable male and female indirect connectors, such as those used on [these boards](https://www.xmos.com/download/final/XK-1A-Quick-Start-Guide%281.1%29.pdf?px-hash=e4305156f983dd2637aa1e3d3041e55d&px-time=1362414844):

[image]

The boards may be daisy-chained.

They are available from [Digi-Key.](http://www.digikey.co.uk/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=S9205-ND&x=0&y=0&cur=USD)
Mating connectors are on the same page.

Comment: I use these connectors all the time, for instance to connect (PIC and ARM) in-circuit-programing tools to my target PCBs. For increased density, use double row connectors.

Comment: Plus you can buy these standard 0.1" headers on aliexpress by the bucketload for ludicrously low cost.

Answer (score 4):

The connector industry term for two PCB's connecting end-to-end is co-planar mating. I declare an interest as I work for GCT.

If you're using standard, 'post and box' connectors, which are the most economical choice there is one key issue to watch out for - the mating centreline of the connector should be  at the perfect height, IE exactly the same for header and socket.  I've had lots of experience designing in these connectors with customers, and often manufacturers datasheets don't list the appropriate information, this is because these connectors often mate with multiple ranges and are not specifically for co-planar mating.  Just choosing a right angle header and socket with the same contact pitch is not always enough!

You'll find many connectors targeted at LED lighting on the market, these are normally used to connect thin and long LED strips in end-to-end fashion, however they tend to be single row and a limited number of circuits (less than 6), which doesn't suit all applications, I notice the original question was for 10 circuit!

You can choose numerous options, as thru hole is covered in another answer I've suggested some SMT options below:

2.44mm (.1") pitch SMT - 
Female - http://gct.co/connector/?series=BG230
Male - http://gct.co/connector/?series=BG080

2.00mm (.079") pitch SMT-
Female - http://gct.co/connector/?series=BF088
Male - http://gct.co/connector/?series=BF035  (BF036 for with locating peg).

1.00mm (.039") pitch SMT- tiny option upto 40 contacts
Female - http://gct.co/connector/?series=BC075
Male - [http://gct.co/connector/?series=BC034](http://hthttp://gct.co/connector/?series=BC034)

Comment: If you do product promotion, you should at least disclose your affiliation with the product. EVERY answer you have given so far (on this SE site) contains a link to a product on http://gct.co. [See FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/228450).

Comment: Apologies, understood, will always disclose my affiliation in future.  All the links I have added are pertinent and relevant to the question, in my humble opinion. Thanks.

Comment: Your answers are fine. I just wanted to point out that a disclosure notice would be a good idea (and is more or less expected), especially if you post own product references on a somewhat frequent basis.

Comment: Sure, thanks, I edited the post to include this too. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: I am looking to do something similar to connect two boards. Unfortunately, the BC034 and BC075 from GCT are unavailable at the usual sources... Digi-Key, Mouser, Newark etc. anything that would sell you just a few to experiment with. SMT single row right-angle or co-planar connectors are scarce. It's a nightmare to find anything that works! If you are concerned with height, it gets even worse. Having an overlap and stacking the connector side of your boards would be easier, as there are quite a few low profile mezzanine connectors. Co-planar is just not very trendy apparently. @Laurence Hill:

Comment: Hi Philippe, GCT don't have a relationship with Digi Key  or Mouser, we sell through Newark. You're correct they are not stocking the BC034 & BC075 lines.  Normally the commercial MOQ is 3,000 pieces, our sales team would normally supply samples to service customers with usage above those volumes.  I checked and we have the following samples in stock BC075-08-A-L x 5   & BC034-05-A-V-0200-L x 5, they are not a perfect match (5 position vs. 8 position) would might help you out?  Send me your address & I'll arrange it laurence.hill@gct-europe.com, also see BG300 & BG301 in Newark, might work?